# Tiva C cannot change value of MDR register

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, keil

i have a tiva c micro controller the `tm4c123gxl` and i have been trying for a while now to use the `I2C` module on the board with a digital accelrometer with no result , i have been trying to set the `MDR` register with a certain value to send but it stays as 0

here is the code i am using for intialization till reaching part where i set the MDR register im using step by step debugging i run the code initially to the assignment step of `I2C3_MDR_R = 0x2D;`

```
void PortDInit(void)
{
volatile unsigned long delay=0;
    SYSCTL_RCGCI2C_R|=0x8;             //1-set clock of I2C of module 3 
    delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;            //2-delay to allow clock to stabilize
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= 0x00000008;      //3-port D clock
    delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;            //4-delay to allow clock to stabilize     
    GPIO_PORTD_AFSEL_R |= 0x03;        //5-alternate function set for I2C mode
    GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R |=0x03;          //6-enable digital functionality for PA6 and PA7
    GPIO_PORTD_ODR_R|=0x02;                  //7-enable open drain mode for I2CSDA register of port A
    GPIO_PORTD_PCTL_R = 0x00000033;   //8-set PCTL to I2C mode
    I2C3_MCR_R= 0x00000010;                     // 9-intialize the i2c master
    I2C3_MTPR_R = 0x00000007;                   // 10-number of system clock cycles in 1 scl period
I2C3_MSA_R = 0x3A // set slave address and read write bit
I2C3_MDR_R = 0x2D;                                  // data to be sent BREAK POINT HERE using single step here yields MDR with same value = 0
I2C3_MCS_R = 0x00000003;                                  // follow transmit condition
    while(I2C3_MCS_R &= 0x40 == 1);                 // wait bus is busy sending data
    if(I2C3_MCS_R&=0x04 ==1)
    {
        //handle error in communication
    }
    else
    {
        //success in transmission 
    }
```

what i have done to reach this code

- carefully understood the I2C protocol how it works etc.
- check the data sheet and follow the initalization steps mentioned there step by step which got me to this code
- i know i should use tivaware library which will be easier but using
  the registers helps me understand more of how everything is working ,
  im still a student
- at first i didnt have the digital enable line as it wasnt mentioned
  to be activated for the I2C but its only logical it should be there
  as we are using digital values i tried with both yielded the same
  output mdr=0
- i am using keil 4 as my IDE and im viewing the values of registers of
  I2C module 3 to know whether data is placed in MDR or not

hope any one helps 
thanks.

Comment: Is that "mdr=0" as in "I have an oscilloscope/logic analyser on the pins and I can see a zero byte being transferred" or as in "I don't understand how this data register works"? If the latter, note what the datasheet says about it being read-sensitive; I don't know this part specifically, but in general one shouldn't assume that anything written into a bidirectional data/FIFO-type register can be read back out again at all.

Comment: @Notlikethat that mdr=0 is neither , in keil , u can select to view what values the different ports of microcontroller hold , its works exactly like a logic analyzer but it shows what ports and what registers contain what data

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but here goes:

in your comments, step 6 says

```
//6-enable digital functionality for PA6 and PA7
```

but it appears you are working on GPIO_PORTD...

maybe its a comment typo  (you meant PD6 and PD7)
but just double check you are looking at the right pins...

Good luck!